# Naming multiples of graphs in ggplot2, r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of data frames called proc.r1. I'm using each data frame to create a graph. Since there are 21 data frames in the list, I get 21 different graphs. So I use the code below to do this.

```
for(i in 1:length(proc.r1)
{
  df1 = as.data.frame(proc.r1[[i]])
  df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
  df1[,42] <-  round(df1[,42],1)
  plotdf1 <- ggplot(df1)+geom_rect(aes(xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5))+
         facet_grid(row~col)+geom_text(aes(x=2.5,y=2.5,label=norm.n,colour="white"))
  print(plotdf1)
}
```

When I generate the graph, I also want each graph to indicate the number of the data frame. So for example, for the first graph, it should have a title "data frame 1" and the second graph, "data frame 2," etc.

I tried to use

```
 +labs(title=paste0("Data Frame #", rep(c(1:21),each=1)))
```

since there are 21 data frames in this particular list but this didn't work.. And I also want the code to be more versatile. If there are 22 data frames in the list, it should still work fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with

```
+labs(title=paste("Data Frame #", i))
```

since you are inside a loop indexed by `i`.